# Angular-ui-grid -- How do I conditionally show cell templates, according to the cell's value

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to show different templates when the value of the cell is different.

1) how can I access the cell's value(`valueOfType`) here?

2) Is it possible to access another column's value(`valueOfNumber`)?

```
columnDefs: [
             { name:'type',
               cellTemplate: '<a ng-class="{style1: valueOfType = '1'}" ng-click=fn(valueOfNumber)></a>'
             },
             { name: 'number'}
          ],
```

3) Can I conditionally show the template according to cell's value? how can I get `cellValue` here?

```
columnDefs: [
             { name:'type',
               cellTemplate: getTemplate()
             },
            ],

var getTemplate = function() {
   if(cellValue == 'something') {
       return template.html
   } else {
       return anotherTemplate.html
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the column value using the scope variable inside the template

```
ng-class=\"{style1:row.entity[col.field]=='1'}\"
```

Here is the full working example,

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid','ui.grid.edit']);
var grid;
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  var myData = [
    {
      id1:"1",id2:"2",id3:"3",id4:"4",id5:"5",
    }, {
      id1:"0",id2:"2",id3:"3",id4:"4",id5:"5",
    },]

    var getTemplate = function()
    {

        return "<div ng-class=\"{style1:row.entity[col.field]=='1'}\" class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>";

    }

  var cellEditable = function($scope){
    if($scope.row.entity.oldId4===undefined)
      return false;
    return $scope.row.entity.oldId4!=$scope.row.entity.id4;
  }

  $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
         onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
      grid = gridApi;
    },
    data: myData,
    columnDefs:[
        {
          field: 'id1',
          displayName: "id1",
          width: 100,

         enableCellEdit:true,
          cellEditableCondition : cellEditable,
           cellTemplate: getTemplate()
        },
        {
          field: 'id2',
          displayName: "id2",
          width: 100,

         enableCellEdit:true,
          cellEditableCondition : cellEditable
        },{
          field: 'id3',
          displayName: "id3",
          width: 100,
          enableCellEdit:true,
          cellEditableCondition : cellEditable
        },{
          field: 'id4',
          displayName: "id4",
          width: 100,
         enableCellEdit:true,
        },{
          field: 'id5',
          displayName: "id5",
          width: 100,
         enableCellEdit:true,
          cellEditableCondition : cellEditable
        },

    ],
}
 $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
          //set gridApi on scope
          $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
          gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope,function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue){
            rowEntity.oldId4 = oldValue;
            $scope.$apply();
          });
        };

 $scope.test = function()
 {
   window.alert("Cell clicked")
 }
}]);
```